# condition for case-insensitive contains jolt to transform

Tags: json, transform, jolt

## Input

```
{
  "type": "my Mnl"
}
```

`type` can contains values like "My mnlString", "My Manual String", "Credit mnl String"

Irrespective of case I want to transform json where `type` to `MANUAL_CREDIT` when value contains ("mnl" or "Manual") & "Credit" or (credit) (case-insensitive)

Irrespective of case I want to transform json where `type` to `MANUAL_DEBIT` when value contains ("mnl" or "Manual") & "Debit" or "Debit" (case-insensitive)

## expected output

```
{
 "type" : "MANUAL_DEBIT"
}
```

or

```
{
 "type" : "MANUAL_CREDIT"
}
```

Default

```
{
 "type" : "MANUAL_PAYMENT"
}
```

## Modified Specs for if else-if else

```
[
  { // convert all letters of the expression to lowercase
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "type": "=toLower"
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "type": {
        "*mnl|*mnl*|mnl*|*manual|*manual*|manual*|*credit|*credit*|credit*": {
          // pipes provide OR logic
          // be careful that the search string might be 
          // in the middle, start or end
          "#MANUAL_PAYMENT": "&2" // &2 copies the literal "type"
        },
        "*credit|*credit*|credit*": {
          "#CREDIT_PAYMENT": "&2"
        },
        "*": {
          "#CARD_PAYMENT": "&2" // # wildcard generates fixed expression
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Getting following error

```
Error running the Transform.
JOLT Chainr encountered an exception constructing Transform className:com.bazaarvoice.jolt.Shiftr at index:4.
```

Comment: Hi Prasad. There's neither `credit` nor `debit` for the current case, then which one do you prefer returning among the expected outputs ?

Comment: MANUAL_PAYMENT would be fine I just want to check how we can have contains, case-insensitive or and conditions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a conditional within a **shift** transformation spec after converting all cases of the letters to lower or upper in order to use in literal comparison easily such as

```json
[
  { // convert all letters of the expression to lowercase
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "type": "=toLower"
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "type": {
        "*mnl|*mnl*|mnl*|*manual|*manual*|manual*": {
          // pipes provide OR logic
          // be careful that the search string might be 
          // in the middle, start or end
          "#MANUAL_PAYMENT": "&2" // &2 copies the literal "type"
        },
        "*": {
          "#CARD_PAYMENT": "&2" // # wildcard generates fixed expression
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

**Edit**: You might use the following shift transformation spec based on the last modification :

```json
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "type": {
        "*mnl|*mnl*|mnl*|*manual|*manual*|manual*|*manual*credit*|*manual*credit|manual*credit*": {
          "#MANUAL_PAYMENT": "&2"
        },
        "*credit|*credit*|credit*": {
          "#CREDIT_PAYMENT": "&2"
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Where would I find comprehensive JOLT documentation?

Comment: @PrasadSDeshpande I couldn't find either, but can recommend some links such as [1](https://erbalvindersingh.medium.com/applying-jolttransform-on-json-object-array-and-fetching-specific-fields-48946870b4fc), [2](https://intercom.help/godigibee/en/articles/3096940-simple-if-else-with-jolt), [3](https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Community-Articles/Jolt-quick-reference-for-Nifi-Jolt-Processors/ta-p/244350), [4](https://cool-cheng.blogspot.com/2019/12/json-jolt-tutorial.html). Take care and don't forget to voteup please.

Comment: Done, thank's for help

Comment: tried following if elseif condition 
"type": {
        "*mnl|*mnl*|mnl*|*manual|*manual*|manual*|*credit|*credit*|credit*": {
          // pipes provide OR logic
          // be careful that the search string might be 
          // in the middle, start or end
          "#MANUAL_PAYMENT": "&2" // &2 copies the literal "type"
        },
        "*credit|*credit*|credit*": {
          // CREDIT_MEMO
          "#CREDIT_MEMO": "&2"
        },
        "*": {
          "#CARD_PAYMENT": "&2" // # wildcard generates fixed expression
        }
        // 
      }

Comment: above specs giving 

Error running the Transform.

JOLT Chainr encountered an exception constructing Transform className:com.bazaarvoice.jolt.Shiftr at index:4.

Comment: Because there are duplication for the `credit` keys @PrasadSDeshpande

Comment: due to comments limitation, updated question for if elseif condition @Barbaros Özhan

Comment: you cannot repeat the search keywords @PrasadSDeshpande the mechanish is not able to select which one is the case.

Comment: what is the work around then?

Comment: Just like | pipe operator for or condition, what is there for and contion?

Comment: As far as I know, there's no an `and` operator but you might replace `"*mnl|*mnl*|mnl*|*manual|*manual*|manual*|*credit|*credit*|credit*"` with `"*mnl|*mnl*|mnl*|*manual|*manual*|manual*|*manual*credit*|*manual*credit|manual*credit*"`  @PrasadSDeshpande . There were exact matches in the previous one.

Comment: is there any way to add conditional modification of properties in `modify-overwrite-beta`?

Comment: the way in my previous comment already does this, but I don't understand if you specifically ask about any other point @PrasadSDeshpande

Comment: it's for another use case where I need to check based on some region like APAC|USA I want to change some property in modify-overwrite-beta

Comment: principally the literals shouldn't match exactly(be different) throughout the keys of objects which are used for conditional logic @PrasadSDeshpande